# Find date when cumulative sum exceeds a reference cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a scenario where I need to identify the 1st date (row 12) in which the sum of consecutive columns (in a row) exceeds my 'On Hand' quantity; for background this is regarding inventory levels. The table on the right is demand for a given date (row 12) on a given sku (not shown). For example in row 13; the sum of G13-L13 is 2,100,000 which exceeds my 'On Hand' in cell E13; I then want to know the date in which a 1st shortage occurs. Any previous date does not return a "shortage" therefore is of no concern.

I attempted multiple iterations of index match to no avail

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZeA5.png)

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2,488,771 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| On Hand | 1st Shortage Date | 14-Aug | 21-Aug | 28-Aug | 4-Sep | 11-Sep | 18-Sep | 25-Sep | 2-Oct | 9-Oct | 16-Oct | 23-Oct | 30-Oct | 6-Nov | 13-Nov |
| 1,991,971 |  | 350,000 | 350,000 | 350,000 | 350,000 | 350,000 | 350,000 | 350,000 | 350,000 | 350,000 | 350,000 | 350,000 | 350,000 | 350,000 | 350,000 |
| 358,204 |  |  |  | 50,000 | 30,000 | 80,000 | 0 | 90,000 | 0 | 90,000 | 0 | 90,000 | 0 | 110,000 | 0 |
| 242,247 |  | 19,884 |  | 0 | 82,400 | 0 | 82,400 | 0 | 82,400 | 0 | 100,000 | 0 | 110,000 | 0 | 60,000 |
| 171,918 |  |  | 20,000 | 0 | 60,000 | 0 | 60,000 | 0 | 0 | 60,000 | 60,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 103,008 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 94,622 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20,000 | 0 | 0 | 20,000 | 0 |
| 134,015 |  |  | 50,000 | 0 | 50,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 70,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 77,368 |  | 19,956 |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20,000 | 0 | 0 | 20,000 | 0 | 0 | 40,000 |
| 362,228 |  | 0 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 |
| 355,992 |  | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 | 95,000 |
| 49,300 |  | 10,800 | 100,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 90,000 | 0 | 40,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 83,520 |  |  |  | 0 | 20,000 | 20,000 | 0 | 70,000 | 70,000 | 0 | 80,000 | 0 | 80,000 | 0 | 0 |
| 41,628 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 39,404 |  | 27,120 |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 58,742 |  |  |  | 20,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 33,720 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 31,736 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 50,112 |  |  |  | 20,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 109,046 |  |  |  | 20,000 | 20,000 | 40,000 | 0 | 40,000 | 0 | 0 | 60,000 | 0 | 60,000 | 0 | 60,000 |
| 29,000 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 26,880 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 50,000 | 0 | 0 | 60,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 45,052 |  |  |  | 0 | 20,000 | 0 | 20,000 | 0 | 20,000 | 0 | 30,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 15,536 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 13,920 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 13,038 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 8,023 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20,000 |
| 6,640 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6,096 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 30,000 | 0 | 40,000 | 0 | 0 | 40,000 | 0 | 50,000 |
| 5,220 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4,104 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4,074 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 40,000 | 0 | 0 |
| 3,586 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3,426 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3,016 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2,940 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20,000 | 0 | 0 | 20,000 | 0 | 0 |
| 2,784 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2,784 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2,724 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2,600 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2,458 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2,436 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| - |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 120,000 | 120,000 |
| - |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| - |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 40,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 125,190 |  |  |  | 30,000 | 70,000 | 40,000 | 80,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 35,118 |  |  |  | 50,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 83,520 |  |  |  | 60,000 | 0 | 40,000 | 0 | 60,000 | 0 | 40,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 114,956 |  |  |  | 0 | 100,000 | 130,000 | 0 | 60,000 | 0 | 100,000 | 0 | 100,000 | 0 | 100,000 | 0 |

Comment: Woops, sorry about that. Just added a picture. In the example listed, I'd look to return the date L12 "09/18/23" as a result. This is the first date in which the cumulative sum exceeds my reference in E13. 1,991,971< 2,100,000 (the sum from G13-L13). Let me know if you need more info

Comment: What is your question? This site is not a code wrting service. What code have you tried, what did it do and how does that differ from what you want? Please read the [help] pages to learn about how to write a good question for this site.

Comment: That lambda answer below looks optimal. And you can also visualize the data by creating a conditional format rule such as `=SUM($C2:C2)>$A2` and fill with some color when true.

Comment: is this about excel or google sheets?

Comment: @M-- this is for excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here You have an option with XLOOKUP and SCAN. SCAN finds the cumulative sum for each row, and XLOOKUP finds it returning the corresponding header or "Not exceeded" if it doesn't happen:

```
=BYROW(A3:A,LAMBDA(each,
IF(each="","",
XLOOKUP(each,SCAN(0,INDEX(C:Z,ROW(each)),LAMBDA(a,v,a+v)),C2:Z2,"Not exceeded",1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have reference to the named range? this is exactly what i am looking for but am having trouble applying it

Comment: There's no named range in my formula, "each" is the way that the formula handles the BYROW process. If you're adapting ranges, you can share and I can help to troubleshoot

Comment: I meant that 'each' goes row by row through A2:A

Comment: hmm.. im getting a #Name error;; https://imgur.com/a/A1zjMFf  https://imgur.com/WbhZBpF

Comment: Ohhh, unfortunately my solution was for Google Sheets, and these are specific functions for this program

Comment: ah. makes a ton of sense. Still super helpful, will be using this. Thanks for your help!!!!